# How can I make an SWT component that looks and behaves like a single table header

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm trying to find a way to make an SWT component that will look like the native table header component, so in windows 7:

[image: Windows 7 Column Header]

I'd like it to have the same hover behavior as the native component too.

I've thought about using an actual table with one column, but I haven't been able to get just the header to fill my entire composite. Here's the code I've been working with for that:

```
package widgets;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class TableHeaderButton extends Composite {

    public TableHeaderButton(Composite parent) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
        makeTable(this);
    }

    private static TableViewer makeTable(Composite parent) {
        TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.FULL_SELECTION
                | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.NONE);

        viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        viewer.getTable().setLayoutData(
                new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));

        TableViewerColumn col = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        col.getColumn().setWidth(100);
        col.getColumn().setText("Text Column");

        viewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);

        return viewer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        new TableHeaderButton(shell);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the code of your last attempt, i.e. the one where you try to use an actual table?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you need it?

Comment: My application has a table of loaded data X columns wide, users pick which columns they are "interested" in. It works, but I use the default eclipse properties view at the minute with combo box selection of columns. My remit is to build something flashy for a user so the new set up will allow the user to click a column in the table and for it to appear in the correct place in the new flashy properties view. I want it to look exactly like the table header so there's no confusion as to what's happened.
 I did want to drag and drop the headers, but it seems you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try to use a TableColumnLayout ?

```
  TableColumnLayout tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
  yourcomposite.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);
  tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(youcolumn, new ColumnWeightData(100, true));
```

For more information take a look at :

[Official doc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/layout/TableColumnLayout.html)

[An example of use to TableLayout](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/05/single-column-tableviewer-and.html)

Comment: Thanks, This get's me part of the way there. I still have one "empty" row showing in the component so i'm now looking at a way to discover the height of the header and force the layout to shrink to that sie.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how to set the height of a SWT table header... What about making your own Composite using MouseMoveListener to change background color ?

Comment: I want it to look and feel exactly like the table regardless of the platform, so that is an option, but I don't think it's achievable.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have managed to create a table with a single column and display just the header in the component, my issue was that tables reserve space for the horizontal scroll bar, which I didn't want. I still can't dynamically change the text though, there may very well be a cleaner way: (PS I know about the memory leak)

```
package widgets;

import org.eclipse.jface.layout.TableColumnLayout;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnWeightData;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;

public class TableHeaderButton extends Composite implements MouseListener {

    private Color highlight = new Color(getDisplay(), 255, 0, 0);
    private boolean selected;
    private TableColumn col;
    private Table table;
    private Composite tableComp;
    private GridData data;

    public TableHeaderButton(Composite parent) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
        this.setLayout(layout);

        Label label = new Label(this,SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("Label:");
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING,SWT.CENTER,false,false));
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        tableComp = new Composite(this, SWT.NONE);
        data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false);

        tableComp.setLayoutData(data);

        table = new Table(tableComp, SWT.NONE);


        col = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        col.setResizable(false);
        col.setMoveable(false);
        col.addSelectionListener( new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                TableHeaderButton.this.toggleSelect();
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        table.setHeaderVisible(true);


        TableColumnLayout tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
        tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(col, new ColumnWeightData(100));
        tableComp.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);
        table.addMouseListener(this);
        this.setText("Text Column");

        this.addMouseListener(this);
        tableComp.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                if (selected) {
                    Rectangle boounds = TableHeaderButton.this.getBounds();
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, boounds.width - 1,
                            boounds.height - 1);
                    e.gc.setForeground(highlight);
                    e.gc.drawRectangle(r);
                    r = new Rectangle(1, 1, boounds.width - 3, boounds.height - 3);
                    e.gc.drawRectangle(r);
                }
                System.out.println(e.width + " " + e.height);
            }
        });


    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        col.setText(text);
        col.pack();
        table.pack();
        data.heightHint = table.getBounds().height - table.getHorizontalBar().getSize().y;
        data.widthHint = col.getWidth();
        tableComp.pack();   
        this.pack();
        this.getParent().pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        TableHeaderButton b = new TableHeaderButton(shell);
        b.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,false, false));
        b = new TableHeaderButton(shell);
        b.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,false, false));


        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        this.highlight.dispose();
    };
    @Override
    public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
        // Do nothing;

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
        toggleSelect();
    }

    private void toggleSelect() {
        setText("Supercalifragilistic expialidocious");
        selected=!selected;
        redraw();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm having all sorts of layout issues with this though. Packing and grids and bears! oh my!

Comment: Glen, what memory leak issue are you talking about? Just curious because I use a lot of SWT and might be something I don't know about.

Comment: Sorry, originally I was creating a new Color from the display every time the highlight was drawn.